# Most efficient way to return parent rows and child aggregates in one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship.  I want to create a view/query that displays all columns from the parent row and aggregate totals from child rows.  This is a scenario I've been encountering pretty often and I can't help but feel like I'm missing a much better, obvious solution to this problem.  One that I've used are multiple joins against the child table, such as:

```
SELECT vt.*, COALESCE(count(mvAyes.*), 0) as Ayes, COALESCE(count(mvNoes.*), 0) as Noes  FROM VoteTable vt 
LEFT JOIN MemberVote mvAyes on mvAyes.VoteId = vt.Id AND mvAyes.Vote = 'Aye'
LEFT JOIN MemberVote mvNoes on mvNoes.VoteId = vt.Id AND mvNoes.Vote = 'No'
GROUP BY vt.Col1, vt.Col2 ... (all columns in Vote table)
```

The other solution is to use correlated sub queries, which as I understand it are pretty inefficient, although I assume the multiple join solution above is pretty inefficient as well.

So, is there a better solution that I'm not aware of?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler solution:

```
SELECT vt.*,
       sum(case when mv.Vote = 'Aye' then 1 else 0 end) as Ayes,
       sum(case when mv.Vote = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as Nos
FROM VoteTable vt left outer join
     MemberVote mv
     on mv.VoteId = vt.Id 
GROUP BY vt.Col1, vt.Col2 ... (all columns in Vote table)
```

You can simplify this further by doing the group by in the subquery:

```
select vt.*, mv.ayes, mv.noes
from vt left outer join
     (select VoteId, sum(case when mv.Vote = 'Aye' then 1 else 0 end) as Ayes,
             sum(case when mv.Vote = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as Nos
      from MemberVote mv
      group by VoteId
     ) mv
     on vt.id = mv.VoteId
```